# Does Xamarin UItest support on locally? Or only for App center now?

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

My enviroment is Windows 10, Visual Studio 15.8.3, Android simulator V27(8.1 Oreo)

I have search and watch many video about the Xamarin.UItest on YouTue for testing the Xamarin.forms application on locally(The visual studio android simulator).

However, I follow their steps cannot work:
1. Mose Youtube videos published before the March 2018. The "**Xamarin Test Recorder**" is discontinued for Windows on March 31st. I cannot follow their ways.

2. The Microsoft only points out that "Xamarin UITest component can be used with Xamarin.Forms to write UI tests to run in the cloud on hundreds of devices." But they did not say we can use Xamarin.UITest only on localy testing.

My question is "May i only test my Xamarin.forms application on the local Android simulator using the Xamarin.UITest"?

If not, does it mean I have to upload my application to App center to complete the testing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.UITest does support running tests locally on both Android and iOS.

[This blog post](https://xamarinhelp.com/running-xamarin-uitests-locally/) looks pretty good if you want an introduction to setting it up.

You can also reach out to the MS support team on App Center (create and account and use the Intercom support widget in the bottom right of the screen). Someone from the App Center support team should help you with any support issues you might have.